# How to set/get ridge of symbol edges in matplotlib scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

carr = np.array([[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1]]) # RGBA color array
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
h = ax.scatter([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3], c=carr)
h.set_edgecolor(carr) ## also tried h.set_edgecolor('none')
plt.draw()
```

But the marker edgecolors remain black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the colors as the `edgecolors` kwarg to `scatter`.  (Note the plural.)

E.g.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

carr = np.array([[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1]]) # RGBA color array
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
h = ax.scatter([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3], c=carr, edgecolors=carr)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: ...Is modifying the object afterwards impossible?

Comment: It shouldn't be, but I can't seem to get it to work, either. Could be a bug... I'm still trying to dig a bit deeper...

Comment: Thanks - if not obvious to you it's not worth it. matplotlib just doesn't make sense. Every other similar programs (R, Matlab) was much more intuitive...